# Cannot get two CSS elements to be next to each other

Tags: css

I'm not the best at CSS and cannot figure out what's wrong.  Think it might be the 
 tags I'm using in my sidebar.   I would like the nav element with the "vert" id and the div element with the "text-container" id to be NEXT to each other, but the way it is going, it's sending my stuff in the "text-container" into the footer, which is unacceptable.

I'm baffled as to how to get them next to each other.  I know elements can be next to each other as it worked in my nav element with the "hor" id with all the a elements next to each other with no problem.

I think it might be the 
 tags, but don't know what I can do about it.   I could just axe the navbar as I already have that in the header, but I just spent a lot of time on the navbar to now have to kill it and wish I could keep it.

```
  <html>
    <head>
    <title> The Resorts </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
    </head>
    <body>

    <style>

    h1
    {
    font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;

    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;

    }

    h2
    {

    font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;
    font-style: bold;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    }

    #text-container
    {
      width: 1045px;
      height: 690px; */
      zoom: 1;
      margin: 0;
      display: inline-block


    }

    #text-container:after
    {
    clear: both;
      content: ".";
      display: block;
      height: 0;
      visibility:hidden;

    }

    #text-container > p
    {
    font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    }



    </style>

    <div id="content">
    <div id="logo">
    <img src="./logo.png"></img>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
    <nav id="hor">
    <div><a href="home.html"> Home </a> </div>
    <div><a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a></div>
    <div><a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a></div>
    <div><a href="snowReports.html"> Snow Reports </a></div>
    <div><a href="eventsAndActivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a></div>
    <div><a href="planTrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a></div>
    </nav>
    <div id="middle">
    <nav id="vert">
    <a href="home.html"> Home </a> <br/>
    <a href="mountains.html"> The Mountains </a><br/>
    <a href="resorts.html"> The Resorts </a><br/>
    <a href="snowReports.html"> Snow Reports </a><br/>
    <a href="eventsAndActivities.html"> Events &amp Activities </a><br/>
    <a href="planTrip.html"> Plan A Trip </a>
    </nav>

    <div id="text-container">
    <h1>   The Resorts </h1>
      <h2>   The West Resort </h2>
        <p>
    The West Resort has everything from wide-open beginner areas to challenging terrain parks to gladed tree skiing hideaways.  It has a young, energetic feel, but there's more to it than just jumps and jibs.  West is 

    home to the Children's Sports Center, the Bullwheel Bar and Grill and the Foggy Goggle where fashion shows, movie premieres and live performances are held on a regular basis.
       </p>

    <h2>  The East Resort </h2>
     <p>
    The East Resort boasts the longest trails in the region serviced by a single high-speed quad.  Its long, groomed, cruising trails make it perfect for carving, but it is also home to the Olympic Bowl, the longest, 

    steepest bump run in the region.  After a quick ascent on the Diamond Peaks Express, you'll find an additional 20 acres of beginner terrain up top.  With 1,600 vertical feet of uninterrupted corduroy, the East 

    Resort offers traditional skiers and snowboarders a true alpine experience without having to journey far from home.

      </p>

    <h2>  The North Resort </h2>
      <p>
    The North Resort is the perfect family-friendly ski resort with 70 acres of gently rolling terrain and historic, log cabins that are terrific for exploring.  It is big enough to offer a true winter experience but small 

    enough to maintain its historical warmth and charm.  Spend the afternoon shushing down the slopes or warm up by the fireplace with a cup of hot chocolate at the North Lodge.  It is one of the region’s oldest 

    base lodges with ties that go back to the Big Pines ski clubs of the 1940s.

       </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footercontainer">
    <footer>
    &copy;  2016   

    </footer>
    </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>



==main.css==

#logo
{

border: 1px dashed purple;
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}

#logo > img
{
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}


#content
{

 border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: 500;



}


nav
{


      border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;
  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 170%;

}

nav#vert
{
width: 220;;
height: 540;
margin: 0;

}

body { 
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #422520;
  background-image: url(./image8.jpg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;

   background-size:cover;
  text-align: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

#footerContainer
{

 border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;

}

footer
{


    border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;


  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;

  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 170%;

}

#container
{
  border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1045px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: 690px;

}


nav > a
{

color: #ccccff;

}

nav#hor > div
{

border: 1px solid white;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
}

nav#hor
{
width: 1000px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0;

}



nav#hor > div >  a
{

color:  #ccccff;
}



nav#hor>div:hover
{

background-color: #01ff02;

}
```

Comment: You should use flexbox.

Comment: Not sure what that is.

Comment: May end up using li and ul.  That might do what I wanted and eliminate the need for the br tags.

Comment: Read up on Display:block and Display:inline-block, as well as the float property. Using those will get you what you want.

Comment: I wish now to get it so that the stuff in the middle (the text-container or whatever I called it.)   I could, I guess, just use an iframe if nothing else works, but was hoping to figure it out.   I've tried the margin elements but they aren't doing it.

Comment: Think the "padding" property will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

https://jsfiddle.net/og9wpLmw/

- I coloured the two blocks green and red to make them obvious
- I fixed & amp; by putting ; on the ends
- I fixed  by making it
- I made boxes next to each other using display:table-cell;
- I put all the CSS into the css file
- I fixed the widths in nav#vert by including px in the measurement.

Here is the css that makes the difference:

```
#text-container {
  width: 1045px;
  height: 690px;
  */ zoom: 1;
  margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;
  background-color:red;
}
nav#vert {
  background-color:green;
  width: 220px;
  height: 540px;
  margin: 0px;
  display:table-cell;
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't cover some of the obvious gaps in knowledge. Say the OP wants to change the width of the text-container, and makes it wider. Now he has no idea why they are no longer next to eachother...

Answer (score 0):

it might be because your "vert" and/or your "text-container" have too big of widths.

Answer (score 0):

You have a fixed width nav - the width is set to `220px`, but then you've got padding / margin etc. so it ends up being `270px` wide (nb. If you're not familiar, right click on an element in a modern web browser and select "inspect" you can easily measure elements and check out their properties in CSS).

So to fit your other text-container to the right of it you need to reduce it's width to allow for the width of your nav. This can be achieved easily by using `calc`

```
width: calc(100% - 270px);
```

Add that CSS to your text-container (and remove other width declarations) and it'll work. It's not best practice, but you can enforce this declaration to take precedence by adding `!important` giving you:

```
#text-container {
    width: calc(100% - 270px) !important;
}
```

You just need to add that in, or amend your existing CSS and you're good to go.

Comment: PS. When creating a layout like this it's much easier to build the blocks and your layout framework first - get the layout you want, and then introduce the nav bars and other bits and pieces. Once you've got the layout you want you can test in diff browsers and pull it about a bit to make sure it behaves how you want before making the problem more complicated with other bits of code.

Answer (score 0):

That works, but the problem I noticed later down the line is that if I have an iframe as the first element in "text-container" and don't have something before that iframe, then the nav bar is messed up again.

Is there another display thing I could use?