# Having trouble once I added iframe

Tags: css, iframe

This is sort of the same issue I asked here:  [Cannot get two CSS elements to be next to each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37846581/cannot-get-two-css-elements-to-be-next-to-each-other/38387535#38387535)

However, this time, it's messing up when I added an iframe.  I tried applying different styles, even to the iframe, but it doesn't appear to be working.  I also messed with the CSS of the ul and li that I added to the side nav bar (didn't help, though changing the ul property to display: table-row;  did fix another issue I had with something else.)

My main plan was to have an iframe to another group of pages.  (My restaurant pages might have more than one tab for each restaurant, but I had been wondering how to have a "back" thing to my ski resort (where the restaurants are) so the user could go back to them.   I then thought, why not just have an iframe instead?

However, once I added the iframe, the trouble I had before (see previous stack overflow link above) suddenly came back.

main.css:

```
#logo
{

border: 1px dashed purple;
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}

#logo > img
{
width: 1050;
height: 75;

}


.floatleft
{
float: left;

}


.floatright
{
float: right;

}

#content
{

 border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;


width: 960px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: 800;



}


nav
{


      border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;
  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 110%;

}

nav#vert
{

 width: 220px;
  height: 540px;
  margin: 0px;
 display:table-cell;


}



body { 
  color: #000000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #422520;
  background-image: url(./snow_mountain.jpg);
   background-repeat:no-repeat;

   background-size:cover;
  text-align: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
}

#footerContainer
{

 border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 980px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;

}

footer
{

    border: 10px solid transparent;
padding: 15px;


  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1000px;

  background-repeat: repeat-y;

  border-image-source: url(./blue-diamond.gif);  
  border-image-repeat:repeat;
   border-image-slice: 30;

background-color: 2211ff;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;
color: white;

}


footer > a
{
color: white;
font-family: "Impact", Times, serif;
font-size: 14px;

}

#container
{
  border-left: 3px solid #283379;
  border-right: 3px solid #283379;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 1050px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  height: 750px;

}


nav > a
{

color: #ccccff;

}

nav#hor > div
{

border: 1px solid white;
float: left;
padding: 10px;
background-color: #000044;
}

nav#hor
{
width: 1000px;
height: 50px;
margin: 0;
font-size: 110%;

}


nav#hor a
{

color: rgb(0 0,238);
}


nav#hor > div >  a
{

color:  #ccccff;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 100%;
}



nav#hor>div:hover
{

background-color: #018802;

}

h1
{
font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;

font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 36px;

}

h2
{

font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 26px;
}

h3
{

font-family: "MV Boli", Times, Serif;
font-style: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
}




#text-container
{





border: 2px solid cyan;



   width: 1005px;
  height: 690px;
  */ zoom: 1;
  */ margin: 0;
  display: table-cell;


 padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;


}



#text-container:after
{
clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility:hidden;

}

#text-container > p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}

.left img
{

float: left; 
padding: 0 20px 20px 0;

}





.left > p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}


.right img
{
float: right;
    margin: 0px 0px 15px 20px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;

}



.right > p
{
font-family: "Myriad Web Pro", Times, Serif;
font-size: 18px;
}


nav#hor ul
{
list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000044;

}

nav#hor ul li:hover
{
  background-color: #018802;

}


nav#vert ul
{
list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #000044;
    display: table-row;

}
nav#hor li
{
float: left;
border: 1px solid white;.

}

nav#vert li
{
float: left;
border: 1px solid white;.

}


nav#vert  li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
  //  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


 nav#hor  li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
  //  color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 8px 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
}


nav#hor   li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #018802;
}

nav#vert   li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #018802;
}


 li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content ul li
{

width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
      color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
     z-index: 1;

}

#eAndADropdown
{


}

#restaurantDropdown li
{
background-color: #000044;
border: 1px solid white;

}

#restaurantDropdown  ul
{
border: 1px solid white;

}



#restaurantDropdown:hover
{
  background-color: #018802;
}

#restaurantDropdown a
{
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);

}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
     border: 1 px solid white;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}

li  a
{

color: rgb(0, 0, 238);
}
```

testingMongoose.php

```
    <html>
<head>
<title> The Mountains </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./main.css">
<link rel="icon" href="./ski_icon.png">
<script src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
 $( document ).ready(function() {

    $("#container").css("height", 800);


  });

  </script>

</head>
<body>





<?php include 'topandside.php';?>

<div id="text-container">



<iframe src="./index.php" width=700;  height=620;></iframe>


  </div>
</div>
</div>

<?php include 'footer.php';?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This time, having display: table-cell;  for both nav#vert and #text-content doesn't appear to be enough like it was before.

Comment: no you want separate pages not iframes of your own pages onto one page wordpress may be for you https://wordpress.org/

Comment: This isn't a wordpress page.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong.

Comment: It would seem that perhaps I need to find the parent of both #text-container and nav#vert as that might be the issue.    However, what seems to be moving is that when I add the iframe, the ul in the nav#vert goes down a couple hundred pixels and the spot of #text-container seems to go down, if not the white space, then the content of #text-container.  (At least, that is what my Inspect Element function on the browser is showing.)

Comment: Interestingly, when I changed the css of the ul in nav#vert to position: absolute, it appears to almost get it correct, but the ul is a bit too far to the right now and is kind of overlapping with my #text-container and the iframe.   However, when I changed it have the nav#vert be absolute, it REALLY overlapped with the #text-container and the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

float: left on the nav#vert seems to have fixed that issue, though it broke some other things (though I should be able to fix those.)

Comment: "oh look! I fixed..er" #theWorldOfCSS